# CRC exploring encoding principles(reserve)

Tags: crc16

We are looking for a solution to the problem of guessing the result value of crc16 with a specific Hex input.

hello. Currently, I am working on estimating the result of crc-16 using specific hex data.

I have figured out the type of input hex value and the crc-16 algorithm, but the result value does not match no matter how the hex value is combined, so I leave a question.

The types of hex values are 0x170, 0xA, 0x00, 0x31
The CRC-16 algorithm used is CRC-16-CCITT XMODEM (Poly = 0x1021, Init = 0x0000).

And the result you want to output is 0x6121 or 0x2161.

It is thought that 0x0170 and 0xA among the above input hex are mixed and divided in some way and input to CRC-16 (for example, after AND operation with 0x017A, division into 0x01 and 0x7A), 0x01, 0x70, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x31 in order Input, 0x31, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x70, 0x01 Even if you change the input order in various ways, such as inputting in reverse order, the result does not come out.

Can you tell me how to find an input sequence or hex input data combination that can solve the above problem?

Waiting for your reply.
thank you

Comment: What the heck do you mean by "type of input hex value", and "the types of hex values are"? What is `0x170`? Is that two bytes? In what order? What exactly is the sequence of _bytes_ on which the CRC is calculated?

Comment: When there is a result value that is output by receiving specific data with crc, we are working on estimating this input data.

For example, if you enter the values 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x09 sequentially, the final output is 0x5A76, and you want to estimate 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x09 from 0x5A76.

Comment: The input values that are known with certainty are 0x170, 0xA, 0x00, and 0x31, and the result value is 0x6121 or 0x2161 by bit division or mixing the input order.
What I want to know is which process did the input order or bit division.

Comment: Presumably, since the input of crc16 is 16 bits, 12 bits 0x170 and 4 bits 0xA are combined to make 16 bits 0x170A, and divided into 8 bits again to input 0x17 and 0x0A in that order.

But I don't know the exact process, so I'm posting the question here.